# implement the message dependency in Netty

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, netty

all

I'm using Netty to implement a client program, which has to finish the handshaking process before it sends/receives data traffic from the server

To ensure the correctness of handshaking process, the server will send me a BARRIER message to indicate that all messages received before this BARRIER must be processed and answered before I process the messages after BARRIER,

Does netty provide any API to implement the requirement of this BARRIER?

Thank you

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to handle it in the ChannelInboundHandler implementation or ChannelUpstreamHandler implementation (depending on if you use Netty 4 or Netty 3).

Comment: Hi, Norman, thank you for your answer. but how can I do it? how can I track if the messages before BARRIER has been processed?